# Unable to log spark job output

Tags: scala, logging, apache-spark

I have created a small program in scala to be run in spark environment. I have a standalone cluster configuration. I submitted the job and the job run successfully on the worker machine. I can see the result in my console, but when I open the browser to see the worker logs, it does not print anything in the stdout. Only stderr has some logs. I am using println to print to print in the program. Am I missing something

Here is the program

```
object SimpleJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "/var/log/syslog" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark log file reader");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

Updates
Here is my log.properties file.

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [the link I posted in the comments for zero323's answer](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/no-stdout-output-from-worker-td2437.html) has the answer for you. Basically, the worker output will NOT have the output, but instead the driver will contain that logging. Everything in the main program, NOT in a closure will be run through the driver.

Here is a sample pseudo-program with comments of where logging will end up:

```
object SimpleJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    ...
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => {
      println("Closure Stuff")//Displayed/Logged in the worker
      line.contains("a")
    }).count()
    println("Stuff")//Displayed/Logged in the driver
  }
}
```

Also, per the link provided, I am fairly positive that stderr displays the log4j output, whereas stdout displays the `println` output

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin. This helped and it worked. Is this documented in Apache spark site?

Comment: Actually, not really from what I can tell. While the documentation with Spark is VERY good, it does still lack in spots